# How to script an an exponential function that decrements the value of the exponent every iteration so that the exponent does not grow?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bc, math

New to Linux and having problems getting this script to run.

Been working on something to take large numbers and use the remainder (modulus) to store the result ( to save memory ).

Using the bash shell I am trying to compute 78390^91025(mod 180577) So using the base 78290 the power of 91025 and applying the modulus of 180577.

I wish to obtain the following logic: 
 y=base
 for i = 1 to the exponent-1
 y := (y*base) mod 'modulus'
 next i
 print y

In doing this I hope to save memory and storage while still obtaining the correct result.

I've been tinkering around with the code and now cannot get it to run..
Where am I messing up?

```
#!/bin/bash

#   k^x (mod n)
#   with k=78390, x=91025, n=180577 ?
#   Script runs but no output, 
#   pretty sure it is close

powmod() {
 let "a=1"
 let "k=$1"
 let "x=$2"
     let "n=$3"
     while (( x )); do
       if (( x % 2 )); then
            (( a = a*k % n ))
            (( x = x-1 ))
       fi
          (( k = k*k % n ))
            (( x = x/2 ))
     done
     echo $a;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input, the desired output, and the actual output.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, you want to calculate `k^x (mod n)` with `k=78390`, `x=91025`, `n=180577`. The simplest way is indeed to repeatedly multiply the base (`k`) to an accumulator, as your pseudo-code presents. Here's a Bash function to do that:

```
powmod() { 
    local a=1 k=$1 x=$2 n=$3;
    for (( ; x; x-- )) { 
        (( a=a*k % n ));
    };
    echo $a;
}
```

Now, `powmod 78390 91025 180577` prints `125`. (The result agrees with [what Wolfram Alpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=78390%5E91025(mod%20180577)).)

Note that you need to initialize `a` to one, not to the base, since an exponent of zero should return one, not the base (`k^0 = 1`, regardless of `k`).

Alternative implementation in `bc`:

```
k=78390
x=91025
n=180577
a=1
while (x > 0) {
    a=a*k % n
    x=x-1
}
a
```

Not surprisingly, `bc` is faster than Bash.

---

Instead of the simple loop, a smarter way would be to use [the square-and-multiply algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). It's significantly faster, since it only uses `log2(x)` operations, rather than `x` as the above does.

In Bash:

```
powmod2() { 
    local a=1 k=$1 x=$2 n=$3;
    while (( x )); do 
        if (( x % 2 )); then
            (( a = a*k % n ))
            (( x = x-1 ))
        fi
        (( k = k*k % n ))
        (( x = x/2 ))
    done
    echo $a;
}
```

That's rather fast with numbers of this size, but note that you get silent failures if the temporary values (`a*k` or `k*k`, before the modulo) get larger than Bash can handle. (The numbers here are fine, since `180577*180577` fits in 64 bits.)

I can't come up with a trivial way of detecting the overflow, without hard-coding a limit, so you might want to use `bc` in any case:

```
k=78390 
i=91025         
n=180577
a=1     
while (i > 0) {
        if (i % 2) {
                a=a*k % n
                i=i-1
        }
        k=k*k % n
        i=i/2
}    
a
```

<sub>(Sticking the call to `bc` in a shell function should be trivial.)</sub>

Comment: That is great, thank you for taking the time to explain it to me.

Comment: I try to run  it from the terminal as an executable and it runs but does not give me any feedback?